# function address in libc?

Tags: c, linux, libc

I am trying to obtain the address (in hex) of function `exit()` provided in libc, but I am not sure where and how to find it.

Anyone knows the way to find it please share some idea. Thank you!

Comment: All the answers are good, but you should realize that `exit(3)` is a standard library function invoking the `_exit(2)` syscall which is not really a function but a system call (you could invoke it with assembler code without any ordinary function calls, even if the `_exit` function from libc is wrapping the syscall as a function callable by C)... The real work of system calls is done inside the kernel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need the address of the `exit` function already present in your process, see answers by Grijesh and others. But if you need to resolve the libc `exit` function *by name*, for example because libc's `exit` has been shadowed by another library, you can obtain it with `dlsym`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE     /* for RTLD_NEXT */
#include <dlfcn.h>
/* ... */
void (*exit_addr)(int) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "exit");
```

For `dlsym` to resolve, you'll need to link with `-ldl`.

Comment: Thanks to appreciate my answer and thanks for your good technical answer :)

Comment: This was really helpful. To add a little bit of info that had me stuck for a few minutes, the command to link with ldl would be for example `gcc -o getptr getptr.c -ldl`. The -ldl comes after the gcc stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will work:

```
printf("%p", (void*)exit);
```

> [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html):
>
> `"%p"` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printable characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 5):

The address of any function is just its name (without the parentheses). You'll need `#include <stdlib.h>` as well. To set an initalised pointer:

```
void (*p)(int) = exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use gdb as follow:

```
gdb ./yourprogram
break main
run
print exit
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xb7e4b7f0 <exit>
here is exit() address----------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p", exit);
```

You will have to include stdio.h for printf and stdlib.h for exit.  This creates a function pointer to exit and prints it.